# Connect to C Server from Node.js Client

Tags: c, node.js, winapi, websocket

**Goal**

I have a `server.exe` running on PC_1 with IP `10.211.55.10` listening for connections on port `15842`.

I have a `XAMPP` http server running on PC_2 with IP `10.211.55.8`.

My goal is to open http://10.211.55.8/edu-connect/gate.php and be able to connect to my `server.exe` through a `Node.JS` application with `WebSocket`.

**Research**

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239074/connect-javascript-websocket-to-c-winsock) from another user trying to accomplish a similar task. However, although I have used Javascript for many years, I never dabbled with Node, I am confused as to how this user got the Client to connect to the Server when the WebSocket is initialized on `ws://192.168.43.205:80` and the server is running on port `10011`.

**Question**

How do I go about writing my Node.js client to connect to my CAPI server. Are there any examples available?

**Note**

I have already read [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) on WebSockets, and have written a small library (in C/WINAPI) to communicate with a WebSocket client.

Comment: You're not clear (or are confused) about the architecture of this setup. Who's the server and who's the client? Are you trying to connect two process on the same machine, or is there a protocol between these two processes over some communication line?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Wait, let me update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install:

```
npm i websocket
```

And then your client code

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        //when the connection is closed
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        //what you want to do upon receiving a message in the topic "message"
    });

});

client.connect('url', 'echo-protocol');
```

Comment: I think socketio is obsolete now that WebSockets is common everywhere.

Comment: I'm looking for a `WebSocket` approach. Hence the tag.

Comment: And I can connect to the `server.exe` even if its not running on port `80`? Would something like this be valid `client.connect('41.104.116.52:15842')` ? Also, if 'message' is what I use to receive responses. What do I use to 'send' replies/messages?

Comment: That would be valid as long as you open that port on your machine